# Why is Visual Studio 2015 solution loading project rather than Nuget Package?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I'm running VS 2015 Update 3 and am seeing something quite strange.

I created a .xproj project (lets call it "ProjectA") which I deployed as a Nuget package to the Nuget store.

I then created a new solution and a new .xproj project (lets call it "ProjectB") from which I referenced the Nuget package for ProjectA.

There seemed to be an issue so I removed the package reference from my project.json file, added the ProjectA .xproj to my solution and debugged the issue successfully. I then removed ProjectA from my solution, re-deployed ProjectA to the Nuget store and referenced the updated Nuget Package for ProjectA from ProjectB.

However, for some reason, whenever I open my solution or try and restore my packages, it still tries to load the ProjectA .xproj into my solution... even though there is no reference to it in the Solution file.

This is extremely strange behaviour. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to stop the .xproj loading into the solution when it has been removed?

Comment: projects information are saved to the .sln file, my understanding is that you could edit the .sln file in your solution folder, remove the projectA, if you open the .sln file again, it would not launch the ProjectA project in your solution explorer.

Comment: That's what makes this so confusing. There is no reference to ProjectA in the .sln file. The only thing I can think of is that it's caching something somewhere. If I remove the folder containing ProjectA then obviously it doesn't load but there is no error and ProjectB successfully utilises the Nuget Package.

Comment: can you share a screen shot about your solution explorer window which includes the Project A in your issue? Is it a reference file or the whole project? Just create a new solution which has no this reference or nuget package in your project B, and then unload the projectB, compare the .proj file with your previous projectB's .xxproj, did you find any differences in the .xxproj file?

Comment: Any update? Would you please share the latest information about this issue?